# LazyLoad for amCharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am working on `amCharts` Donut chart.

I am able to create a chart and giving events to both slice and labels.

For my chart, I added a `rollOverSlice` event.

Then I added some script for the `LazyLoad` to the chart in order to create the chart once the page scrolls to that particular section.

Now the chart is creating with LazyLoad,
but the rollover event for the label is not working.

Following is the script used to create the chart and LazyLoad.

**Script**

```
/*Lazy Load code starts here*/
AmCharts.lazyLoadMakeChart = AmCharts.makeChart;

// override makeChart function
AmCharts.makeChart = function(a, b, c) {

  // set scroll events
  jQuery(document).on('scroll load touchmove', handleScroll);
  jQuery(window).on('load', handleScroll);

  function handleScroll() {
    var $ = jQuery;
    if (true === b.lazyLoaded)
      return;
    var hT = $('#' + a).offset().top,
      hH = $('#' + a).outerHeight() / 2,
      wH = $(window).height(),
      wS = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (wS > (hT + hH - wH)) {
      b.lazyLoaded = true;
      AmCharts.lazyLoadMakeChart(a, b, c);
      return;
    }
  }

  // Return fake listener to avoid errors
  return {
    addListener: function() {}
  };
};
/*Lazy Load code ends here*/

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "pie",
  "pullOutDuration": 0.5,
  "pullOutRadius": "5",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataProvider": [{
    "title": "Aaa",
    "value": 10,
  }, {
    "title": "Bbb",
    "value": 10,
  }, {
   "title": "Ccc",
   "value": 10,
  }, {
    "title": "Ddd",
    "value": 10,
  }, {
    "title": "Eee",
    "value": 10,
  }],
  "titleField": "title",
  "valueField": "value",
  "labelRadius": 50,

  "radius": "35%",
  "innerRadius": "85%",
  "labelText": "[[title]]",
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "baseColor": "#7a4436",
  "pullOutOnlyOne": true,
  "startEffect": "easeOutSine",
  "pullOutEffect": "easeOutSine",
  "pullOutRadius": 0,
  "balloonText": "",
  "listeners": [{
    "event": "rollOverSlice",
    "method": function(e) {
      var dp = e.dataItem.dataContext;
      document.getElementById("result").innerText = dp.title + ':' + dp.value;
    }
  }]
});


chart.addListener("init", function() {
  var d = chart.chartData;
  for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
    d[i].label.node.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
    d[i].label.node.style.cursor = "pointer";
    chart.addEventListeners(d[i].labelSet, d[i]);
  }
});
```

Is it possible to create the chart with `LazyLoad` and rollover for the label too?

If it is not possible, is there any way to animate the chart again when scrolls down to the section having the chart?

**[Here's the fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ztyv37bu/3/)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `makeChart` function returns an object, which only has a mock `addListener` method. So obviously the later added listener won't work. You have to wait until the chart is created and then add it.

```
function handleScroll() {
    var $ = jQuery;
    var hT = $('#' + a).offset().top,
    hH = $('#' + a).outerHeight() / 2,
    wH = $(window).height(),
    wS = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (wS > (hT + hH - wH)) {
        if (!b.lazyLoaded) {
            b.lazyLoaded = true;
            visible = true;
            chart = AmCharts.lazyLoadMakeChart(a, b, c);
            var d = chart.chartData;
            addLabelEvent();
            chart.addListener("drawn", addLabelEvent);
            return;
        }
        if (!visible) {
            chart.animateAgain();
            visible = true;        
        }
    } else {
        visible = false;
    }
}
```

(For some reason neither `init` nor `drawn` handler are fired at initialization, but it works without now [I think its because the DOM is already loaded completly and the creation is synchronous then])

I've extracted the lines to add an event listener to a separate function, so you can call it at initialization and when the chart is drawn. This way the handler should be always registered.

```
function addLabelEvent() {
    var d = chart.chartData;
    for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
        d[i].label.node.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
        d[i].label.node.style.cursor = "pointer";
        chart.addEventListeners(d[i].labelSet, d[i]);
    }
}
```

I've also introduced a variable `visible` so you can call [reanimate](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#animateAgain) the chart if it gets into view another time.

Here's the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ztyv37bu/7/).

Comment: roll over label event not firing after resizing the window.

Comment: @Ullas Made an edit. As I already mentioned: It's weird that no handler is executed at chart initialization.